# Transitive closure in given graph (with unknown dimensions)

Tags: python, networkx

I have a directed graph

```
a,b,.....,z,a',b'.... c''
```

but i dont know how many elements are inside. It can various in different words. 
They maybe for example connected in a way a-b,b-c,c-d, ....

i would like to add to this graph transitive closure which will create connections between a-c, a-d, etc.

What should i change in my algorithm to reach transitive closure working for any given graph. Right now it is working just for a graph containing 3 nodes.
My code is below.

```
for x in G:
# Extract all neighbours of neighbours of x (from G)
all_nh = []
for y in G.neighbours(x):
    all_nh += G.neighbours(y)

    # Remove from the list of neighbors the current node and its immediate neighbors
    all_nh = set(all_nh) - set([x]) - set(G.neighbours(x))

    # Create new edges (x -> z)
    edges = map(lambda z: (x, z), all_nh)

# Add them to the new graph
TC.add_edges_from(edges)
```

Okay I tried to implement also pseudo code presented below. But still I need help cause compiler is returning a lot of bugs. For ex. TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

```
class FlowGraph:
    def __init__(self):
      self.G=nx.DiGraph()
      self.I=[]
      self.O=[]

F2=FlowGraph()
#F2.G=nx.Graph()
F2.G.add_node(1)
F2.G.add_node(2)
F2.G.add_node(3)
F2.G.add_node(4)
F2.G.add_edge(1,2)
F2.G.add_edge(2,3)
F2.G.add_edge(3,4)

def transitive_closure(G):
  TC = G.copy()
  n_nodes = len(G)
  #print(n_nodes)
  for i in range(n_nodes):
    for j in range(n_nodes):
        for k in range(n_nodes):
            if TC.has_edge(i,k) and TC.has_edge(k,j):
                TC.add_edge(i,j)

Z = transitive_closure(F2.G)
nx.draw(Z, with_labels = True) 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to compute the transitive closure is to use Floyd-Warshall. Let `TC` be the transitive closure graph and `G` be the original

```
TC = G # copy all edges from G to TC
for i in range(n_nodes):
    for j in range(n_nodes):
        for k in range(n_nodes):
            if TC.has_edge(i,k) and TC.has_edge(k,j):
                TC.add_edge(i,j)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Cna u help me in debugging a code cause i am getting n-nodes is not defined error.

Comment: This is just psuedocode you'll have to adapt to your own.  `n_nodes` is the number of nodes.